# The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a WPF application which I want to use on multiple machines.
I can connect to it on the same machine but I can't connect from another machine. I know I have to enaple TCP/IP connection and I have to start server browser, but the error which occurs says the following:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.
This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

The server PC have more than one Sql Server installed (2005,2008,2008 r2). The target database is 2008r2.
I tried to do this on another local network and it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear (although there's a possibility of mis-configuration) that your firewall is stopping the connecting. First of all see if you can ping the server you're trying to connect to. If that works then check the firewall on the server to make sure SQL server is allowed to receive network connections.